# Get all possible unique combinations of values from multiple lists in ColdFusion

Tags: arrays, list, coldfusion

Here's one of those ColdFusion things that seems like it should be so easy... but I'm not finding the easy path.

I have an array of lists.
The array could be any size, and the length of each list can be any size.
(this can be manipulated into a multi-dimensional array, whatever... the point is, i have a list of lists)

For example

1. 129,128,127
2. 130,131,132
3. 135,133,134
4. 137,138,136
5. 140,139
6. 141,142

Or a short version... it can vary

1. 13,14,15
2. 11,12

What I need is an array, query or some other data structure
containing all the possible unique combinations, taking one from each list in order ... so for the short version, there would be 6 unique combinations. For the first longer example, we would have 3*3*3*3*2*2 = 324 unique combinations.

Counting them is easy... but what's the best way get the actual combinations in a structured format? 
Must be missing something simple... I've been very close for hours now!
:-/

Comment: I've read your question five times and I have no idea what you want. You say what is the best way to get them into a structured format. You already have an array of lists, and for the purposes of counting the length of them and multiplying them that is reasonable. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I need to generate all the possible combinations which use an item from each list.

So, for the short version i would get 6 results:
13 11, 
13 12,
14 11,
14 12,
15 11,
15 12

Essentially, I need to create a matrix of values based on the given lists.

Comment: This looks like the same thing in PHP - last post on the page: http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=194046

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's my take.
Credit goes to the php function in this post on codingforums.com: http://www.codingforums.com/showpost.php?p=945289&postcount=3
I just figured how to re-write it in cfml.

```
<cfscript>
public array function array_cartesian_product(_arrays=[]) {
    var result = [];
    var _arrayslen = arraylen(arguments._arrays);
    var _size = (_arrayslen) ? 1 : 0;
    var _array = '';
    var x = 0;
    var i = 0;
    var j = 0;
    var _current = [];

    for (x=1; x lte _arrayslen; x++) {
        _size = _size * arraylen(arguments._arrays[x]);
        _current[x] = 1;
    }

    for (i=1; i lte _size; i++) {
        result[i] = [];

        for (j=1; j lte _arrayslen; j++) {
            arrayappend(result[i], arguments._arrays[j][_current[j]]);
        }

        for (j=_arrayslen; j gt 0; j--) {
            if (arraylen(arguments._arrays[j]) gt _current[j])  {
                _current[j]++;
                break;
            }
            else {
                _current[j] = 1;
            }
        }

    }

    return result;
}
</cfscript>
<cfset arrays = [[129,128,127],[130,131,132],[135,133,134],[137,138,136],[140,139],[141,142]]>
<cfset r = array_cartesian_product(arrays)>
<cfoutput>#arraylen(r)#</cfoutput>
<cfdump var="#r#">
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is _exactly_ the thing!

The output is a list of unique combinations, each combination uses one item from each original list, in order. Perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work.  Loop through each item in the first list and make a combo with each item in lists 2 and 3, then check to make sure its not already in the known list, and if not, add it to the combinations list.

```
<cfset list1 = "1,2,3" />
<cfset list2 = "4,5,6" />
<cfset list3 = "7,8,9,1" />

<cfset combinations = [] />

<cfloop list="#list1#" index="i">
  <cfif not arrayFind(combinations,i)>
    <cfset arrayAppend(combinations,i) />
  </cfif>
  <cfloop list="#list2#" index="y">
    <cfif not arrayFind(combinations,y)>
      <cfset arrayAppend(combinations,y) />
    </cfif>
    <cfif not arrayFind(combinations, "#i#,#y#")>
      <cfset arrayAppend(combinations,"#i#,#y#") />
    </cfif>
    <cfloop list="#list3#" index="z">
       <cfif not arrayFind(combinations,z)>
         <cfset arrayAppend(combinations,z) />
       </cfif>
       <cfif not arrayFind(combinations, "#i#,#y#,#z#")>
         <cfset arrayAppend(combinations,"#i#,#y#,#z#") />
      </cfif>
    </cfloop>
  </cfloop>
</cfloop>

<cfdump var="#combinations#" />
```

Comment: hi Sean, thanks for that , the thing is, I might have any number of lists with any number of elements.

Answer (score 0):

OK so you need to loop through the array of lists . At each iteration you need to loop through the list at that position against each of the remaining lists.

So at position one iterate against 2 3 4 5 6
At position two iterate against 3 4 5 6 and so on